# Need to change cash to cashier's check without bank account (Just arrived to the US)

Tags: united-states, banking, cashier-check

I arrived in the US 10 days ago. I got my SSN. The DMV told me I will get my ID in about 10 days.

I have to pay the rent plus some months prepaid which is USD 11,000.

My question is:
I have my money in cash. The apartment manager doesn't accept cash and has asked me to bring in a cashier's check.
How can I change my cash to a cashier's check without having a bank account?

Comment: $11,000? How much is the rent per month?

Comment: in LA 2 per month but because of having no credit and co-signer... they asked us about 6 months prepaid

Comment: @ZoyaAmin do you have a job - in that case better to try to find something else  - 6 months prepaid is too much.

Comment: In my state, Massachusetts, that's illegal. I am a real estate agent, licensed in my state only. I don't know if this differs in other states.

Comment: I just arrived... so My 2 sons and I don't have job. and I tried many many landlords to convince them I dont have problem to pay the rent monthly... but they always tell me: you are new in usa... and you dont have enough credit and you have no co-signer

Comment: What is the legality of not “accepting” cash?

Comment: @JDługosz perfectly legal to not accept cash unless it is for repayment of a debt. https://www.federalreserve.gov/faqs/currency_12772.htm

Comment: In the US, Amscot caters to situations like this, and most landlords I've worked with except either cashiers check or money order

Comment: You can't open a bank account with your SSN and your passport as identification?

Comment: Also, according to the [California Department of Consumer Affairs](http://www.dca.ca.gov/publications/landlordbook/when-rent.shtml#rulesgoverningsecuritydeposits), it looks like your security deposit is limited to a total of three months rent, no matter what the deposit is used for. I know it's not related to the need to change money, but you should know you're being taken advantage of.

Comment: If the landlord's bank isn't too far away, you could potentially get permission to simply deposit the cash directly into his account.  Just be sure to keep the receipt.

Comment: You can open a bank account without an SSN, or even any money. I did this one day after arriving in the US. I had to get approval from the bank manager, but at the end of my first 24 hours I had an account and a cheque book. I used TD Bank in Manhattan. I deposited $20 and two days later my relocation funds were deposited. It can be done, you just have to find a friendly bank with a good manager. This might be difficult, but I had huge success with TD, if they operate in your region.

Comment: I also sympathise with your situation. It took me 2 months to find a house to rent, and I only got it due to a sympathetic landlord who was once in the same situation as me when he came to America in the 90s. But you can do it. You just need to be firm and not give up. Know your rights, and the rules. Good luck!

Comment: @MarkHenderson tnx for your sympathy :) today I opened an account in Wells Fargo bank. and the land lord may accept me by money order but he will get 6 mounth prepaid :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A cashier's check costs money to get and is not connected to an account.  You have cash.  You should be able to get a bank to sell you one, even without an account.  Find a bank where you would like to open an account and explain the situation.  I can't guarantee that that will work, but I would expect it to do so.  If not, the bank can probably suggest an alternative.

You might also ask the landlord if you can do it with [postal money orders](https://www.usps.com/shop/money-orders.htm).  I am positive that you can buy those with cash.  You might have to buy a bunch to reach your desired amount.  Or perhaps a [Western Union money order](https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/money-order.html) might be better.

You also might be able to open an account with your passport and Social Security Number (SSN).

Comment: +1 for money orders, if the landlord accepts them. They are as good as cash, and you don't need any government papers to buy them. If the post office won't sell you a single money order for $11k, ask what is the largest amount of money that they can give you on a single money order, then buy a few of those until you get your total of $11k. Each money order has a small fee.

Comment: @pedro thanks... but I think there is $1000 USD limit for money order. and for 11000 USD I must get 11 money order, true?

Comment: @ZoyaAmin - yes, you can buy 11 USPS money orders. They cost $1.60 ea so the total would only be $17.60. First make sure your landlord will accept them, and please save all of your receipts from both the post office and the landlord. (Note a single bank check may be cheaper than $17.60, I think some banks are about $10 for a check even without an account there.)

Comment: @TTT: From http://pe.usps.com/Archive/HTML/DMMArchive20030810/S020.htm:  "Any customer whose daily total of purchased money orders is from $3,000 to $10,000 must also complete Form 8105-A and show identification bearing the purchaser’s photograph, name, and address."  That seems to be exactly the kind of ID the OP doesn't have.  It also says there it's forbidden to buy over $10,000 on any one day, so it will take at least two days.

Comment: @NateEldredge - wow, great find! If they deny OP because of a lack of an address yet, then that would be quite the chicken and egg problem. I think a bank check would be simpler.

Comment: @NateEldredge Why wouldn't a photo ID issued by the (foreign) government and showing the purchaser's most recent (foreign) address qualify?

Comment: Transactions including over $10,000 cash requires a [Currency Transaction Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_transaction_report) according to [BSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_Secrecy_Act), which means most financial institutions are unlikely to do transactions for that amount for non-customers due to the reporting requirements.  However, opening an account should be an easy fix there.

Comment: @NateEldredge LoL ... good point... chicken and egg :))) but today I found that I can get money order by my SSN and temporary DMV ID (because the ID on temporary paper has photo and the temporary ID will be exactly the final ID) (and also that post office should be kind ;) )  . . . . ..  also because the amount is 11000 USD... he told me buy 10000 today and buy 1000 after 3 days (11 x 1000 USD) and the amount is 1.6 per money order

Comment: @ZoyaAmin Watch out for inconvenience traps with 'availability of funds' if/when you open an account.  In other words, if you open an account, don't put this rent money, or your grocery money into the account.  Keep that money out.  Once you're a customer, use the cash to purchase a cashier's check at the cashier's window.  Once you receive your checkbook or debit card for that account, you can deposit income, etc. and use the account for paying expenses.  But until the initial holding period is over, the money is effectively frozen.  Even if it's a cash deposit.  (banks differ on this).

Answer (score 10):

If you have an SSN and foreign passport - it's all you need to open account, so just open it and order a checkbook. It will take some time before they will issue it but most probably they'll give you some checks to use till that very moment.

So basically you should:

- Come to the bank, open account, put some money on that account.
- Order a checkbook associated with that account.
- Obtain a two-three checks right there and voila - you have some small piece of paper you can give to your landlord.

Also I strongly suggest you to open two accounts - one would be for you and one for rent exclusively. The thing is that check could be cashed any time and it's pretty annoying exercise to keep that in mind.

Comment: Today I went to Chasebank and they didnt accept to open the bank account... they said you must have 2 things: SSN and DMV ID ..(or rental documet, or forexample electricity bill with your name on it... But i told them Now I am in hotel). I told them my DMV ID will come in about 10 days ... and in this week I must pay the rent....

Comment: maybe chasebank has difficult rules... maybe I must try another bank

Comment: @ZoyaAmin have a try in Wells Fargo, in my experience it is the most friendly bank for newcomers.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion... I will try it tommarow

Comment: Take other ID, such as your foreign driving license and identity card, a notarized letter from your employer with your name on it, or even a bank statement for your foreign bank, if you have them. With your passport and SSN, that is more than 2 pieces of ID. Also ask around local ex-pats for bank recommendations. Or go to a bank that knows and trusts your employer. (Ask your employer where they bank.)

Comment: @ZoyaAmin You should have received a temporary ID from the DMV?

Comment: @ZoyaAmin - from your comment above, it seems that Chase bank would accept your rental agreement. If you have rent due already, then you should already have a lease agreement- could you bring that to the bank?

Comment: Just a note: you do not need an SSN. You need your foreign passport and to be in the country legally (a visa page would help immensely as well). I opened an account without an SSN while I was living at a hotel. It required bank manager approval and scrutiny of my legal status, but it took less than a day.

Comment: @MarkHenderson ... Hi... good. which bank did you open an account in?

Comment: @TTT this is vacational apartment. and Chase bank said: it is not home rental it is something like hotel

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes,,, I have the temporary... bank of america today said: we may open an account but after 30m of checking ducuments they said: go and come back tommarow I should ask from my manager

Comment: @ZoyaAmin I mentioned that I opened my account with TD Bank. But they only operate in Canada and on the east coast of the US.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest thing would be to go to [walmart and stock up on 1000$ money orders paying a 70 cents fee for each](https://www.walmart.com/cp/632045). your landlord would almost certainly accept money orders, but double check first just in case. i say stock up because you can't get a money order for more than 1000$ and they usually won't let you buy more than 3 per day.

alternatively, you can probably open a bank account using your ssn and your passport.  look for any bank offering "free" checking, and they should be able to give you a few "starter" checks on the spot when you open the account. in any case, they can certainly get you a cashier's check for free or a small fee.

side note: if you want to shop around for a checking account, look for a bank or credit union offering a "kasasa" account.

Comment: I am a landlord. I won't take money orders. I do however take cash.

Comment: fortunatly the landlord today accept that get money order from me. and post offices sell money order 10.000 USD (10x1000) ...